# I want to create an object for the below code in my main... so how do i do it?

Tags: c++, function, class, object

i have a query with the following code..

```
class CDocument : public dom::Document, public CNode
{
    friend class XMLDoc;

protected:

      CDocument(XMLDoc *pd, cell_t pc) : CNode(pd, pc)
        { } 
 }
```

now i want to create an object for the above class in my file, so how should i do it?

Comment: Please could you explain better what you want to achieve? One single instance of the object? a way to create objects with that protected constructor?.

Comment: i want to call a method of that class in my main program.. so for calling that method, i need to generate an object or a pointer to the object of that class.. so how should i supposed to do it?

Comment: You will need some kind of factory or subclass. It looks like is not your code, there must be any subclass for CDocument or factory, where you can instantiate it, if not you will need to modify the class as @lgbo suggests.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a static public method to create a new object.

```
class CDocument : public dom::Document, public CNode
{
  friend class XMLDoc;

protected:

  CDocument(XMLDoc *pd, cell_t pc) : CNode(pd, pc)
    { } 
public:
  static CDocument * create(XMLDoc *pd,cell_t pc){
    return new CDocument(pd,pc);
  }
}
```